# How to avoid selection in ListBox changing datatemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, listbox, selecteditem

Im using VS2012 in a WPF application. I have a listbox in a mainwindow. The listbox has the background = null - which means the background equals the mainwindow background.

The listbox has a datatemplate, but i have an issue, that for the last selected item in the listbox, it changes the background color to white? How can I avoid this?

I have uploaded a picture for illustration.

*EDIT - this picture illustrates the problem
http://i57.photobucket.com/albums/g202/RolleKn/pic2_zps94f2907a.jpg

Regards.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the highlighting upon selection? Just wondering, how would the users know that an item was selected then, unless if this is your intent.

Comment: Show your problem related code. How you are selecting the item and after that what are you performing on it.

Comment: I want it to set the background to "null" after it looses focus. Because it leaves the background to white, like shown on the picture uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the change in background of the SelectedItem, you have to Overwrite the control template of the listboxitem.

Try this

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can it be solves just using the trigger? <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

Comment: I have already removed the section that shows the highlight on selected item from the template. The reason I used a template here in case you have more than one place where this is done.

Comment: Im a rookie to xaml ... Could you help me by pointing out where i need to change your code, if i have a listbox called "lboxName" and the template called "nameTemplate"?  Edit: Is this style meant to be implemented in my templates or in listboxes?

Comment: You can place it in your window.resources if you want it to affect on listboxitems in that window or even in the list box (to try it out). so you can do something like this <ListBox> <ListBox.Resources>
    The style above                    
    </ListBox.Resources></ListBox>

Comment: It works! I dont get a white background when i lose focus in a list (when clicking in one list and then in another) However .. I dont get any kind of indication that an item is selected. I would still want to see which item is selected the old way(the item gets marked),. So your solution works halfway, or am I misunderstanding the code?

Comment: What I did is remove the the IsSelected  propertytrigger. If you want for example the foreground color to change when you select an item you can add this trigger to change the color of the foreground to a different color